# How to Copy rows based on 2 column criteria and paste specific data in VBA?

Tags: vba, copy, criteria

I have 4 columns (A,B,C,D,E) in my source sheet. I want only rows for the first 2 columns (A,B) to be copied to the target. These two columns are copied based on value in columns (D,E) of "Yes". In addition I would like to copy to the target sheet in Columns (C,D) the headings of Columns (D,E) from the source sheet
For Instanc, Here is the source sheet content

```
  A  |  B |  C  |  D |  E  |
testX| 123| xyz | No | Yes |
testY| 125| xyz | Yes| No  |
```

What I would like to see copied to the target sheet is as follows

```
  A  |  B |  C |
testX| 123|  E | 
testY| 125|  D |
```

E and D are headings from the target sheet. Also, If you notice, I am not interested in column C from the source sheet and I do not need it to be copied in the target sheet

My code does correctly read the "yes" criteria, but it copies entire rows and It does not do anything to copy the headings. So what I get is the exact copy of the source sheet.I.e.,

```
  A  |  B |  C  |  D |  E  |
testX| 123| xyz | No | Yes |
testY| 125| xyz | Yes| No  |
```

I need some help to get this project done.
Thank you

```
Sub CopyYes()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim Source As Worksheet
    Dim Target As Worksheet

    ' Change worksheet designations as needed
    Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    j = 4     ' Start copying to row 4 in target sheet
    For Each c In Source.Range("D5:E1000")   
        If c = "Yes" Then
           Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(j)
           j = j + 1
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```vb
Sub CopyYes()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim Source As Worksheet
    Dim Target As Worksheet

    ' Change worksheet designations as needed
    Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    j = 4     ' Start copying to row 4 in target sheet
    For Each c In Source.Range("D5:E1000").Cells   
        If c = "Yes" Then
           c.EntireRow.Cells(1).Resize(1, 2).copy Target.Cells(j, 1)  'ColA, B
           Target.Cells(j ,3).Value = Source.Cells(4, c.Column).Value 'Header
           j = j + 1
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```